# Get response from webView after redirect React-Native, Paytabs

Tags: javascript, react-native, paytabs

I’m setting up an online payments using Paytabs payment Link in react-native WebView.
And on redirect in the payment webPage it display a json Response.
is there any way to to access that response in my react-native App?
I already tried onMessage and onNavigationStateChange.

this is payment Flow and the response i wanna get in the App

[react Native WebView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Xv5R.jpg)

[WebView action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4Lys.jpg)

renderContent() {
    return (
       
     console.log("event",navEvent)}
     onMessage={(event)=> console.log("event",event)}
     style={{ flex: 1 }}
   />)
   }

Comment: Give this  library try https://dev.paytabs.com/docs/express-checkout-v4.html

Comment: https://github.com/Gardencoder/react-native-paytabs

Comment: Hi, did you manage to get the data from the webview action?